# how to use take() with every index of array in laravel

Tags: sql, database, laravel, eloquent

Hi I want to gate 3 models against every brand and I use this code in my controller

```
 $brand = Brand::with (['models' => function ($q){
            $q->take(3);
    }])->get()->toArray();
```

But it takes only 3 models for the first brand not for all [Here is the image of my dd command](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4wTcp.png) 
SO tell me how to gat 3 models for all brands.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found one solution after get using collection method map you can get 3 models for all brands

```
  $feed= Brand::with(['models'])->get()->map(function ($query) {
        $query->setRelation('models', $query->models->take(3));
        return $query;
    });
```

Comment: This loads *all* the related models from the database and then discards the unnecessary ones. It's better to only load the required models (see my answer).